# Linux (Ubuntu) USB Auth

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, pam

I want to be able to authenticate with PAM using a USB drive with a file on it.  I've read about how to do this with a PAM module that reads the specific USB hardware ID of a device, but if the device malfunctions or is lost, there would be no way to authenticate.  I would prefer to use the method BitLocker uses, requiring a particular file to be found on the drive in order to authenticate.  That way I can keep another drive in a secure location as a backup.

Any other suggestions are welcome.  I just want to require a higher level of security that just a password.

Edit: The existing pam way (that I don't like): http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=17571

Comment: How does "Make the keys on the usb memory stick" imply that it uses the hardware ID of the drive?

Comment: http://www.xtarutaru.com/2010/03/05/ubuntu-pam-usb-authentication/

Comment: @Ignacio: The file `doc/FAQ` in `pam_usb` source _does_: "The USB device is both identified by its manufacturer attributes (vendor, product, serial number) and by a few random bytes called one time pads that
pam_usb writes and updates on the USB device upon authentication."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PAM modules are stackable. It's very easy to configure authentication so that if one module fails, it falls back to asking for a password. So I see no reason for you not to use [`pam_usb`](http://www.pamusb.org/) (as suggested in the Ubuntu Forums thread).

```
auth    sufficient      pam_usb.so
@include common-auth
```

(Note `sufficient` as opposed to `required`)

Comment: That's true, but I'm trying to require the USB.  As in, if someone was to install a keylogger and get the password, they still cannot gain access without the physical device.

Comment: @themicahmachine: 1) If somebody manages to install a keylogger that affects the _login screen_, he must already have `root` access, in which case you're own3d, USB or no USB. 2) A device check like that is merely a _check_, which can be easily bypassed: the same forum page mentions single-user mode, which skips PAM and only checks `shadow`. For such checks to work, you would need strict physical security - locked case, restricted bootloader.

Comment: @themicahmachine: One workaround I can think of is to have one device for yourself and another for `root`. If you lose device A, login as root and configure a new one. If you lose device B, login as yourself, `su(do)` to `root`, configure a new device. // Alternatively, you could require either USB or one-time password (a list of which you stash away in the "backup key" location; there also are PAM modules for token-generated passwords).

Comment: Good points...  I'm marking your answer as correct just for all the good info.  It seems like I can accomplish what I want using TrueCrypt and running full-disk encryption and putting the boot loader on a usb stick.  No USB = no decrypting the drive.

And as far as key loggers... If someone has physical access to the machine they could install a hardware key logger.  USB device that goes inline between the keyboard and the computer... undetectable unless you actually look behind the machine.

Comment: @themicahmachine: In case of hardware keylogger, even your full-disk encryption password will be logged. (But FDE is still a better option than simple USB check, as with the latter the attacker might be able to boot from his own media, bypassing all other kinds of protection.)

Comment: @grawity: yes, a hardware key logger would get the encryption password, but not they key file that resides on the usb stick.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a faq that i typed up a while back. maybe it can be of use.

http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=110813

Comment: Hi jesse, while this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. 
Please take a look here: [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://superuser.com/help/deleted-answers)